# Uploading data from CSV to SQL Sever where CSV have carriage returns

Tags: sql-server, csv

I have a CSV which I need to upload in a table in SQL Server. Usually any csv file is uploaded in that table. But this time, a file with carriage returns has caused some serious uploading problem. Following are the first 2 rows of the csv. Column Description have the data with carriage return.

```
"REV"   "LIFECYCLEPHASE"    "RELDATE"   "INCDATE"   "CHANGECATEGORY"    "EFFECTIVEDATE" "OBSOLETEDATE"  "CLASS" "TYPE"  "number"    "DESCRIPTION"   "PROPOSEDREV"   "STATUS"
"00"    28687   19-OCT-05       200012  19-OCT-05       "Change Orders" "ECO"   "P006508"   "WORLDDSL G.SHDSL PHASE 2:  PCB artwork V11 release to meet the new Anatel conducted emission test requirement from Brazil customer."   "00"    "Implemented"
"01"    28687   04-NOV-05       200012  04-NOV-05       "Change Orders" "ECO"   "P008027"   "Change for WORLDDSL G.SHDSL PHASE 2 V.11 Subassy BOM:
1. change Q1 and Q9 to use 1336419
2. change R89 to R88

Change for WORLDDSL G.SHDSL PHASE 2 V.11 top level BOM:
3. add washiers for all the screws
4. update top assembly drawing to add insulator on main PCB for Ethernet RJ45 connector, and add washiers for each screw.
5 obsolete Ethernet bridge upgrade kit


"   "01"    "Implemented"
```

I use SQL Server's import/export utility. Can anybody tell me how I can fix this problem.

Comment: By "SQL Server's import/export utility" do you mean bcp? Also, which version of SQL Server does this relate to?

Comment: I am using the GUI interface for importing data. It uses bcp or not I do not know. Sorry for the lack of knowledge. I usually work in Oracle. :)

Comment: And I am using SQL Server 2012